# find the numerical index of a list of characters in ascending alphabetical order

Tags: python, sorting, cryptography

I am writing a cryptography program that does columnar transposition. 
a person enters a key as a string, eg, key = 'ZEBRAS'
I need to determine the numerical index corresponding to each letter, in ascending alphabetical order. 
for example,

- **Z E B R A S**
- **6 3 2 4 1 5**

A is the highest, so its rank 1. z is the lowest, so its rank 6. 
I want to store this value into an appropriate data structure, so when i go to encrypt a message, i will read off the column corresponding to position 1 first, and 6 last.

Comment: What is the problem? Creating list `6 3 2 4 1 5`, creating a data structure, encrypting?

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary from sorted & unique group of letters & indices from 1 to length of the string (you need unicity or several indexes will be generated if there are several occurrences of a letters (as shown below, I have added an S to the word):

```
s="ZEBRASS"
us=set(s)
sl=dict(zip(sorted(us),range(1,len(us)+1)))
print(sl)
```

`sl` contains:

```
{'Z': 6, 'A': 1, 'E': 3, 'R': 4, 'S': 5, 'B': 2}
```

To "encrypt", apply the dictionary to your string:

```
sc = [sl[c] for c in s]
print(sc)
```

result:

```
[6, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 5]
```

Comment: does not work for any other case other than this word.

Comment: I wonder how it wouldn't. Have you an example of a word that doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in my question, or comment. I am looking to handle multiple instances of same letters as well. I solved it by creating a class class KeyChar(object):
    def __init__(self,l,pos,w):
        self.letter = l
        self.position = pos
        self.weight = w
    def setWeight(self,w):
        self.weight = w

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the submissions. I am looking for multiple repeated letters to count as a different score. SO "ZEBRASAB" would result as [zebrasab picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW6vq.png)

what i did was essential make a class using the plaintext from the key to find the index of the letters in the string, as well as the alphabetic weight of the letters. then i sorted it by initial weight, and position, then adjusted the final weight to be heavier if in later position in the string.

```
import alpha

class KeyChar(object):
def __init__(self,l,pos,w):
    self.letter = l
    self.position = pos
    self.weight = w
def setWeight(self,w):
    self.weight = w

def getRawKeyList(key):
key_list = []
key_weight_normalized = dict()
i = 0
for c in key:
    weight = alpha.giveAlphabet('u')[c]
    char = KeyChar(c,i,weight)
    i=i+1
    key_list.append(char)
return key_list

def adjustKeyWeights(key_obj_list):
#first sort based off weight
kchar_sorted = sorted(key_obj_list, key = lambda kchar: (kchar.weight,kchar.position))
i=0
for k in kchar_sorted:
    #print k.letter, k.position,
    k.setWeight(i) #readjust weights based on weight
    #print  k.weight
    i=i+1

return kchar_sorted 


# return weighted key sorted by letter weight (smallest letter first)
def getWeightedKeyList(key):
k_adjusted = adjustKeyWeights(getRawKeyList(key))
final_key =  sorted(k_adjusted, key = lambda kchar: kchar.weight)
key_list = getKeyAsList(final_key)
return final_key,key_list



def main():
key = 'ZEBRASAB'
key_obj_list,key_list = getWeightedKeyList(key.upper())
 #DEBUGGING / TESTING
for k in key_obj_list:
    print k.letter, k.position, k.weight

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp list to store the sorted word, and extract the position from the temp list. Below is the sample code:

```
>>> word = 'ZEBRAS'
>>> sorted_word = sorted(word)

>>> sorted_word
['A', 'B', 'E', 'R', 'S', 'Z']

>>> index_string = [sorted_word.index(a)+1 for a in word]
>>> index_string
[6, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5]
```